# Animation design for transitions

Tags: android, animation, graphics

I need to design a component for animation rendering. Because you probably are much smarter than me I ask your opinion.How would you do the following design?

More precisely I want to have a horse which can run, stop, jump and dodge.
I can obtain all the frames needed for all these states. For example, I can draw all the frames containing the horse running(f[1] - f[n]). But what if the horse needs to dodge while running on f[k] frame (1

How can I design this type of transitions? What classes would you use? Do I need to draw transitions for every f[k]?

More details if helps: Design will be implemeneted in Android SDK.

Thank you very much!

Comment: do you have separate images for horse run ?

Comment: Yes, I have a set of images for every state enumerated above. n1 frames form RUN, n2 frames for JUMP etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code . hope it will work

**You need to create animation-list under res/drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/animationFrame"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/es0"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/es1"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/es2"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/es3"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/es4"
        android:duration="100"/>

</animation-list>
```

**Write below code in your activity**

```
private AnimationDrawable m_frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();


imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animationFrame);
m_frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
m_frameAnimation.start();
```